# Anonymous users request to enter email to download files

Tags: 7, ajax, emails, users, files

I have a question that i thought originally i would able to answer myself.

I have a site that show some pdf help files. The files is open to anyone so they can download freely.

The question is how i can still leave it open but when a user click on a file they will requested to enter an email ( like a pop up) after that the could continue as normal.

I don't want in this stage to force the user to create a account.
I don't want the user to verified the email.
I don't want to create a private file system.

I think a first approach will be a javascript. But i want the drupal check and validate the user input {With ajax approach}. The reason is that in a later state i would implement some web service with another Db and it will be nice to have ready the site part.

The validation for now is just to be a valid email format. {abc@abc.abc}

I have already seen [FileField Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefieldmail)

Comment: @Mołot I didn't change anything at my question, i think the question isn't duplicate. The link you provide is just a part of the answer .  A meaningful answer is to address all the little point of the question and not just a big part. This is a Q&A site but also a learning ground.

Comment: If question has distinct parts that can be answered separately, then it's simply too broad.

Comment: I can't argue on that :) But also breaking the question to separately questions will not be the easiest to read on. This is my last comment in this topic.